# magento product export custom options

Tags: magento

I have 8000 products with custom options .
I need to export this to CSV through the magento admin panel.
How can i go about it ?.
ANy change in code is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This module does the job:

http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html